# Let $X$ a topological space and $A\subset X.$ Suppose that $X$ verify the first axiom of enumerability

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Then, $x \in \bar{A}$ if exist one sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ such that $x_n \to x.$

I have tried a lot of things. I imagine that it is easy, I am just not finding the way. I thought the following:

Suppose that $X$ verify the first axiom of enumerability. Then, $x \in \bar{A}$ implies that for each $U \in \mathcal{U}_x$, where $\mathcal{U}_x$ is a system of neighborhoods for $x$, $U = \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}V_n$, where $V_n$ belongs to a basis for $\mathcal{U}_n.$
Once $A\cap U \neq \emptyset$, there is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_n\cap A \neq \emptyset.$ Take $y \in V_n\cap A.$

If we proceed the same way we can take $V_n$ as union countable of basis elements and extract $W_m \subset V_n$ such that $W_m\cap A \neq \emptyset.$ And then we can take another element on such intersection. I imagine that iterating this process I will get the desire sequence. The problem is that I don't know how to proceed.

I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(U_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ be a countable neighbourhood base at $x$ with $U_j \supseteq U_{j+1}$. Any neighbourhood base can be turned into this form by contracting intersections. If $x \in A^-$, then $\forall j \in \mathbb{W}, U_j \cap A \neq \emptyset$. For each $j$, choose $x_j \in U_j \cap A$. Since $(U_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is decreasing, $(x_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is eventually in any neighbourhood of $x$ and thus and converges to $x$.

The converse follows easily by considering $A^{-c}$.

Comment: I am sorry, how can you take the neighborhood base this way?

Comment: @Leonardo Francisco Cavenaghi Do you mean a neighbourhood base?

Comment: yes, I am sorry, I mean exactly this.

Comment: @Leonardo Francisco Cavenaghi Say that $(V_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ is a countable neighbourhood base at $x$. Define $U_m = \bigcap_{j=0}^m V_j$.

Comment: ! I got it!Thank you! Very good.